# could not use windows authentication to connect db, which is available in another system?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to connect another db available in another system using windows authentication. But it works when I connect through sql client. not through code.

connection string has `Integrated Security=SSPI;` but I still get **login failed for VM-MBWEBDEV**

any idea?

Comment: Please post the whole connection string, plus the code that you are using to connect and the exception details that you get.

Comment: Also check the SQL Server error log and review the state. Different states mean different things. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the account your are impersonating does not have permission to access SQL server on a different machine.

You need to make sure that the asp.net worker account has rights to access sql. Otherwise, instead of using SSPI, pass username and password.